# Not able to install both GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

In my ubuntu server I have two apps, one is using GraphicsMagick and one is using ImageMagick but I am not able to install both GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick, when I am installing one then it is replacing the /usr/bin/convert and the convert command is pointing to only one, is there a way to keep both like convert1 and convert2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ImageMagick installs in `/usr/bin/convert`. GraphicsMagick is installed in `/usr/bin/gm`.

In order to use `convert` with Graphic Magick use `/usr/bin/gm convert` or simply: `gm convert`.

For ImageMagick use, as usual, `convert`.